# UNION ALL on 2 tables select with Cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, union-all

I'm running SQL Server 2005. I have 2 tables with the same columns but holding very different data.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
WHERE ItemID IN ('4','2','1') 
ORDER BY 
    CASE  WHEN ItemID = 4 then 1 WHEN ItemID = 2 then 2 WHEN ItemID = 1 then 3 END 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE ItemID IN ('3','1','5','2') 
ORDER BY 
    CASE  WHEN ItemID = 3 then 4 WHEN ItemID = 1 then 5 WHEN ItemID = 5 then 6 WHEN ItemID = 2 then 7 END
```

I need to keep the order of the `ItemID` in the order that they are selected which is why I used `CASE`. This all works fine on each table but I can't find a way to combine them into 1 table of results with the results of each table ordered.

i.e.

```
4 (Table1)
2 (Table1)
1 (Table1)
3 (Table2)
1 (Table2)
5 (Table2)
2 (Table2)
```

Extremely grateful for any and all help.

Comment: If both tables have the same columns and you are using `UNION ALL` to get data from both they are clearly realated. So you should use one table with another column `TypeID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT Table1.* , x.[Order] AS Ord
FROM Table1 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE ItemID
                       WHEN 4 THEN 1 
                       WHEN 2 THEN 2 
                       WHEN 1 THEN 3 
             END) x([Order])  
WHERE ItemID IN ('4','2','1') 

UNION ALL 

SELECT Table2.* , y.[Order] AS Ord
FROM Table2 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE ItemID 
                       WHEN 3 THEN 4 
                       WHEN 1 THEN 5 
                       WHEN 5 THEN 6 
                       WHEN 2 THEN 7 
                    END) y([Order])
WHERE ItemID IN ('3','1','5','2')
ORDER BY Ord
```

Calculated field `[Order]` guarantees that records from `Table1` will come first, followed by records of `Table2`. It also ensures ordering within each `Table1` or `Table2` partition.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e33cb/2)

This is an alternative syntax without the use of `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT Table1.*, 
       CASE ItemID
          WHEN 4 THEN 1 
          WHEN 2 THEN 2 
          WHEN 1 THEN 3 
       END AS Ord
FROM Table1 
WHERE ItemID IN ('4','2','1') 

UNION ALL 

SELECT Table2.*, 
       CASE ItemID 
          WHEN 3 THEN 4 
          WHEN 1 THEN 5 
          WHEN 5 THEN 6 
          WHEN 2 THEN 7 
       END AS Ord
FROM Table2 
WHERE ItemID IN ('3','1','5','2')
ORDER BY Ord
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeee1/1)

Comment: Hey Giorgos, thanks for the reply here. Really appreciate the time you take to help. Message I get from MS SQL 2005 is CROSS APPLY is not supported?

Comment: @Steve `CROSS APPLY` was introduced with SQL Server 2005. There was an error in my query. It run OK now. If you don't want to use `CROSS APPLY` you can use an alternative syntax (chek edit).

Comment: I've ticked it as the answer to the question but it won't let me vote up? I need a reputation of 15 and sadly I'm a newbie at this with just 1...but I'd really like to add credit to you here. Amazing job!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * , 1 as ord
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE ItemID IN (4, 2, 1) 
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT * , 2 as ord
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE ItemID IN (3, 1, 5, 2) ) t
ORDER BY  
    ord,
    CASE  WHEN ItemID = 3 then 4 WHEN ItemID = 1 then 5 WHEN ItemID = 5 then 6 WHEN ItemID = 2 then 7 END,
    CASE  WHEN ItemID = 4 then 1 WHEN ItemID = 2 then 2 WHEN ItemID = 1 then 3 END
```

---

Or

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ord,
        CASE  WHEN ItemID = 3 then 4 WHEN ItemID = 1 then 5 WHEN ItemID = 5 then 6 WHEN ItemID = 2 then 7 END,
        CASE  WHEN ItemID = 4 then 1 WHEN ItemID = 2 then 2 WHEN ItemID = 1 then 3 END) as RowNo 

FROM (
    SELECT * , 1 as ord
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE ItemID IN (4, 2, 1) 
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT * , 2 as ord
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE ItemID IN (3, 1, 5, 2) ) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply shA.t ...really appreciate it. I tried the select but it doesn't maintain the IN order of (4,2,1) and (3,1,5,2). It does the union but results as (1,2,4,1,2,3,5) in other words it just Orders them by ID. Any ideas?

Comment: The inner `CASE` expressions are the wrong way around.

Comment: Damien, nice spot! Eyes of an eagle!!!! I just saw it. Giorgos post solved the problem. Thanks again guys. This is such a great forum!

Comment: @Steve I also remove `'` characters inside `IN` statement ;).